# Can't find folder created by Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I have created a new folder using Xcode, called it `www` and I have added some `html` file. 
The applicatios runs and works fine, but there are no any files or the new folder in the physical space.

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just can not find the project dictionary: `File` -> `Show in Finder`.
If you want to add a folder in your project to make sure it grouped well, you need to: `Create Dict` in your project dictionary and then in your xCode: `File` -> `Add Files to 'YourProjName'`. The reason @Abizern has explained.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a folder to Xcode, you are adding an internal group which does not necessarily mirror the way the files are arranged in Finder.